# Angular 2 (Reactive forms) Listing all validation rules (like pattern, minlength, maxlength) in a form control whether or not in an error object

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am creating a component where I need to list all the validation rules of an input.

home.component.html

```
<input-validation>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="name">
</input-validation>
```

home.component.ts

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
    public myForm: FormGroup;

    constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.myForm = this._fb.group({
            name: ['', [ <any>Validators.minLength(5), <any>Validators.pattern('^[0-9]*$')]],
            address: this._fb.group({
                street: ['', <any>Validators.required],
                postcode: ['8000']
            })
        });

    }
}
```

For template driven forms I am using

> _rawValidators

property of **FormControlName.**

But I noticed that **_rawValidators** does always returns empty array for Reactive forms.

As you can see in above example **formControlName="name"** has two validators here **minlength** and **pattern**. Now unless you starts writing in this input, the *errors* object of **FormControl** is null.

So if anyone could help me to understand how ReactiveForms works(validates) or where it stores all its validators  would be much appreciable.

Thanks

Comment: _rawValidators is not a Angular thing, you should have used some code where validators are assigned to _rawValidators variable?

Comment: What do you mean by _rawValidators is not a Angular thing, you should reference [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/088532bf2e608ab5dce8b58eb37e8e8c644b4c50/packages/forms/src/directives/reactive_directives/form_control_name.ts#L104)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From documentation

> A FormControl constructor accepts three, optional arguments: the
>   initial data value, an array of validators, and an array of async
>   validators.

So you have you validator in an array. You can beforehand assign it to a variable and get it anywhere else. Like

```
this.validator1 = [ Validators.minLength(5), Validators.pattern('^[0-9]*$')]
...
console.log(this.validator1);
```

Comment: Yes, this would be the last option I thought I will use, but it needs a little bit extra work for the users.

Comment: Ok, my bad here users are the developers which will consume my validation library. Does it make any sense to you?

Comment: Still you have to do the job giving your users what they need

Comment: I think we are not on the same page. I am creating a component say **input-validation** like
`<input-validation>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="name">
</input-validation>`

Comment: I dont' get you. But if you think it's relavant to your question, add it to your question to maybe get more help

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but the `validator` property on `AbstractControl` returns a single function which is composed of all validation logic.  If you call that function and pass in the control you want to validate, it will apply all validation and return an object containing information about each validator that failed, or `null` if no validators failed.
For example, on an input with a `minlength="3`" validator, the following is the return value when you only enter 2 characters:

```
{"minlength":{
    "requiredLength":3,
    "actualLength":2
  }
}
```

Whereas it returns the following when a required validator fails:

```
{"required": true}
```